# rename a file using C function rename()

Tags: c, macos, rename

I'm using a Mac. I need to rename a file in the /Library/Application Support/AppName/filename.aiff

This is the system library and not /User/username/Library...

I'm using the `rename(old name, new name)` function. This function doesn't work (even though it doesn't return an error) if I place the file in the /Library/Application Support/AppName directory but it works properly if I place the file, for example, in /User/username/Documents/filename.aiff.

I don't know what the problem is. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: So the `rename` function returns zero, but the renaming doesn't happen anyway?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes. The program completes execution without any problems and does everything else. I even read the file I'm trying to subsequently rename (after reading of course) and write other files to the same directory. The rename function doesn't report an error. It simply doesn't rename the file. gnu.org says this can happen and even probably explains how to solve it but I don't fully understand what exactly I need to do.

Comment: Reading the file, doesn't mean that you enough permission to rename it. Can you show us your code, and log `errno` (or use `perror`) after your `rename` call. You should not have write permission in `/Library/Application Support`

Comment: @Emmanuel I think I understand what you mean. I will try what you suggested but before that, I wanted to say that after executing my code, it doesn't write the files to the directory at first but if I manually rename the file, all the files it was supposed to write get automatically written. But the C program completes execution without showing any errors.

Comment: "*... the C program completes execution without showing any errors*": You did tell the program to check for errors and have them reported, didn't you?

Comment: @alk This is what I had. Is this not the way to check for an error?`temp = rename(sweepFilepath, fullPrFilepath);                 if(temp != 0) { fprintf(stderr,"Cannot prefix Pr to imported file.\n"); }`

Comment: @alk I even tried this and my program executes properly without renaming the file. `if((temp = rename(sweepFilepath, fullPrFilepath) != 0)) { perror("rename"); exit(2); }`

Comment: Assuming `int temp` your 1st example would detect an error, your 2nd would **always** log an error.

Comment: Could it be  you are trying to do a rename over a partition boundary?

Comment: @Emmanuel and alk: It's a permission problem after all. Despite this, the program never really stopped executing with an error message making it hard to figure out. The executable is a part of another piece of software that creates the appropriate folders in /Library/... and sets the correct permissions. I was doing it manually and therefore it didn't work. It's all in order now. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't own the directory you're trying to move files into:

- `/Users/Username/...` *is* a user owned directory, so you're allowed to manipulate files there.
- `/Library` *is not* a user owned directory.

In order to manipulate files in a non-user owned directory you would need elevated permissions. Instead of using `/Library` **you should be using** `~/Library`, which is the user owned directory. `~/Library` is the shorthand name for `/Users/Username/Library`.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I need to use the /Library. It is a restriction I am faced with. If you can suggest how I can get it to work with that, it would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Read Apple's [Secure Coding Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/securecodingguide/Articles/AccessControl.html). It should give you an idea of what's required to elevate permissions within your application. If you're only needing to install files in a non-user owned directory you might want to consider using an installer `.pkg` instead.

Comment: I think that is the problem. I shall look into this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the rename is working fine in other path means the problem should be related to `permission` to access file or with the `path searched for file`.

Comment: I do other things with the file. I'm able to read the file for instance. I can also write new files to the same directory. So I don't see how it can be a permissions problem. Only the rename function doesn't seem to work. On gnu.org it says, One special case for rename is when oldname and newname are two names for the same file. The consistent way to handle this case is to delete oldname. However, in this case POSIX requires that rename do nothing and report success—which is inconsistent. We don't know what your operating system will do. Maybe this is the problem but I don't know what to do.

Comment: I don't know what they mean by delete old name. How can I delete the file and then rename it? Or do they mean delete the name of the file? I'm not sure.

Comment: I think what gun.org describes is the case where you have two `hard links` to the same file.  Note that a file exists independently of the directory entries that points to it, so you can have any number of hard links that point to the same file. If oldname and newname are two hard links to the same file, then I think gnu.org is suggesting that you delete the oldname link (presumably using `unlink(2)` )